# how can i display items in this way using grid in CSS

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

**i'm facing problem with css grid :**

[image: how can i display items in this way]

how can I display items in this way? using grid in CSS. i have just started with CSS grid

**my code :**

```css
.tools {
  .cardscontainer {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: " . c1 c2 . " ". c3 c3 .";
    .c1 {
      grid-area: c1;
    }
    .c1 {
      grid-area: c2;
    }
    .c1 {
      grid-area: c3;
    }
  }
}


}
```

```html
<section className="tools ">
  <h1>Tools</h1>
  <div className="cardscontainer">

    <div className="cards c1">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>
      <h1>Tracker</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div className="cards c2">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>
      
      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div className="cards c3">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>

      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

```
**output**
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ6Bi.png)

**this is the output**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have used grid-template-area but its is not displaying the same properly

Comment: Then show the code!

Comment: looks like a flex display, but grid can do it too with a bit more of CSS to write. use the `[<>]`  button  to share a snippet of what you've done.

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet .As is your snippet won't work , it takes plain CSS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you grid-area should not have empty cells on the first line.

class are all the same for the cards in your CSS

the idea was good but typo got it wrong i believe

here a possible fix:

```css
.tools {}

.tools .cardscontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: " c1 c1 c2 c2 " ".. c3 c3 ..";
  gap: 10px;
}

.cards {
  border: solid;
}

.c1 {
  grid-area: c1;
}

.c2 {
  grid-area: c2;
}

.c3 {
  grid-area: c3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="tools ">
  <h1>Tools</h1>
  <div class="cardscontainer">

    <div class="cards c1">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>
      <h1>Tracker</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div class="cards c2">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>

      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div class="cards c3">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>

      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `12-column` grid always works best because 12 has 2,3,4,6,12 are its factors and we can lots of flexibility when we use it.

I have tried your question by using 12-column grid using CSS-grid, and no empty grid-items are ever required.

Try this one:

```css
.tools{
  width: 500px;
  text-align:center;
}
.cardscontainer{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
  grid-template-rows:200px 200px;
  gap:1rem;
}

.card{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align:center;
}

.c1{
  grid-column:1/7;
}
.c2{
  grid-column:7/13;
}
.c3{
  grid-column:4/10;
}
```

```html
<section class="tools ">
  <h1>Get a Quick Overview for</h1>
  <div class="cardscontainer">

    <div class="card c1">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>
      <h1>Tracker</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card c2">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>
      
      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card c3">
      <i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>

      <h1>Converter</h1>
      <a>Learn more</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

**Note:** You can easily use media queries to style your items as per the design on small screen sizes or larger screen sizes by just changing where to place the cards.